# XHTML formatting issues with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I am currently having problems with my website in IE (non-compatability mode): www.cueprojects.ca.

When I switch to compatability mode the page looks fine.

Two problems are: the navigation sub-menus are pushed over by apx 75 pixels, and the news scroller text does not become hidden and overflows the entire page (even though css property is set to hide).

Attached is a screenshot of IE non-compatibility mode:

[image]

and how it should look like (in IE compatibility mode and FF, Chrome)

[image]

Comment: I hate IE more than almost anything on this planet

Comment: so, which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @ Phil, agreed!!!!  @spudley, I am currently using IE9

Comment: You probably want to use the ` X-UA-Compatible ` header to force the latest rendering mode. I only got this problem using IE9 with compatibility mode turned on. ` X-UA-Compatible ` would fix that. If you want to fix this for the native IE7 client do bear in mind that the share of IE7 is very low, and probably not worth your trouble (> 3%)

Comment: Thank you, I tried defining that as IE7 and it didn't work, so I was discouraged to try any other type. I have set it to IE8, and seems to have resolved the issue with IE9. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem because you didn't position your ULs correctly.

To make sure they're positioned below their 'parents' you should make the LIs they are in relative with `position: relative;` and secondly applying the style `left: 0;` to the ULs. IE has quirky behaviour when you don't specify the positioning explicitly.

I don't know which exact bug this is but I would advice you to avoid IE8 and below like a plague (or at least IE7, which is pretty much not used anymore).

Next to fixing this, you should still use the X-UA-Compatible tag as either a  http header or meta tag in html.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem with IE8, other browser have fine but IE not
with the following method IE work fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php # my php codes go here ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I start my page with First line of above code, then put my session data, configs and require files
and in last I start my page with html start tag

if I move the first line after my php codes IE not work in all modes and make visual problems but with the above codes all work fine

Hope you understand what i wrote.

Comment: As long as your php code before the <html> tag does not echo any output, this should not be the case. Can you verify that when you put your php code above the html declaration, check the source from your browser to make sure there are no errors or other code above <html> that shouldn't be there.

Comment: php code does not have any echo, just includes and requires and some functions that check if browse is valid or not if not redirect!! the problems happen if i put this "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">" after my php codes but if i add it at document first line every thing works fine